# React & Redux : cannot read property of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to write an application in react, and I faced the issue of having to manage the state for so many components, so I wanted to use redux. From what I read, Redux doesn't work on the root component, so I created an intermediate component named it "wrapper" that will wrap everything and manage the state of my application. So now I have my original root component and a wrapper component. I am trying to get some props in this wrapper component using redux, but the props aren't populated for some reason and I can't figure it out.

Here's my code:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
//SPFX references
import { DefaultButton, IButtonProps } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
import { Panel, PanelType } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Panel';

//custom references
import { IRootProps } from '../props/IRootProps'
import { IRootState } from '../states/IRootState'
import { ITile, ITileHeader, ITileItem } from '../props/ITileStructure'
import store from '../main/store'
import { openPanel, closePanel } from '../actions/panelAction'

//Styles references
import rootStyles from '../styles/RooComponent.module.scss'
import commonStyles from '../styles/common.module.scss'

//Components references
import PanelComponent from './PanelComponent'
import FooterComponent from './FooterComponent'
import DiscardChangesDialogComponent from './DiscardChangesDialogComponent'
import BladesRootComponent from './BladesRootComponent'
import TilesListComponent from './TilesListComponent'

class RootComponent extends React.Component<{}, {}>{
    tiles: ITile[] = [];

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <AppWrapper />
            </Provider>

        )
    }
}

class AppWrapper extends React.Component<IRootProps, IRootState>{
    tiles: ITile[] = [];

    constructor(props: IRootProps) {
        super(props);

        if (this.tiles.length === 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                this.tiles.push({
                    key: i,
                    tileName: 'tile ' + i,
                    tileImageUrl: 'image url ' + i,
                    tileOrder: i,
                    headers: []
                });
            }
        }
    }
    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <div className="RootComponent">
                <DefaultButton onClick={() => this.props.panelProps.openPanel()} className={commonStyles.defaultButton} >Configure Tiles</DefaultButton>
                <Panel
                    isOpen={this.props.panelProps.isPanelOpen}
                    // tslint:disable-next-line:jsx-no-lambda
                    onDismiss={() => {
                        this.setState({ showPanel: false })
                    }}
                    type={PanelType.extraLarge}
                    headerText="Tiles configuration"
                    hasCloseButton={false}>
                    <PanelComponent />
                </Panel>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

let mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        panelProps: state.panel,
    };
};

let mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        openPanel: () => {
            dispatch(openPanel());
        }
    };
};

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppWrapper);
export default RootComponent;
```

This is the code for the ../main/store:

```
import {createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {Store} from 'redux';

import panel from "../reducers/panelReducer";
let store =  createStore(
    combineReducers({
        panel
    }),
    {}
);

export default store;
```

and ../reducers/panelReduce looks like this:

```
//(state, action) => 
const panelReducer = (state = {
    isPanelOpen: false
}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "OPEN_PANEL":
            state = {
                ...state,
                isPanelOpen: true
            };
            break;
        case "CLOSE_PANEL":
            state = {
                ...state,
                isPanelOpen: false
            };
            break;
    }
    return state;
};

export default panelReducer;
```

However, the code is getting executed and at the line : `<Panel
                        isOpen={this.props.panelProps.isPanelOpen}` it's telling me cannot access isPanelOpen of undefined. For some reason Redux isn't connected the right way.

P.S I am still a beginner in Redux so I might be doing things wrong, if anyone can point me to the right direction.

Comment: it should be this.props.isPanelOpen as there is no properties called `panelProps`

Comment: Hi CRayen, but I want to combine multiple reducers. In my store file, I have let ``` store =  createStore(
    combineReducers({  ``` so wouldn't be there be another object between props and .isPanelOpen? .. Also when I log this.props, it give me this  { }

Comment: did you try `let store =  createStore(combineReducers({panel}));` instead of `let store =  createStore(combineReducers({panel}), {});` ? Basically you set the initial state to `{}` so it will not work...

Comment: @CRayen `panelProps` is defined in the mapStateToProps function, so `this.props.panelProps.isPanelOpen` is correct

Comment: @CRayen I tried it like this let store = createStore(combineReducers({panel})); .. same error

Comment: @Oliver Thats right. I missed.  I also suspect, in mapDispatchToProps,  openPanel is assigned a non return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you didn't use the connected `AppWrapper` component inside your `RootComponent`

You can create a constant AppWrapperConnected : `const AppWrapperConnected = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppWrapper);` and use `<AppWrapperConnected/>` inside the `RootComponent`

Moreover I think it will be easier to maintain if you split `RooComponent` and `AppWrapper` in two separate files

Another advice is to rewrite `mapStateToProps` like this

```
let mapStateToProps = (state) => state.panel
```

so you can directly use `this.props.isPanelOpen`, I think `panelProps` is useless here

Comment: Thanks @Olivier. But how do I reassign AppWrapper .. I just tried it, it says it's not a variable. Since it's a class component.

Comment: I edited my answer, you use `let AppWrapper = class extends React.Component...` or create a new variable `AppWrapperConnected`

Comment: By the way, why remove the panelProps from the state? What if I have another property related to something else with the same name?

Comment: Yes but here it seems useless as You don't have another prop with the same name...

Comment: OK. Thank you :D

Comment: I have another follow up question. Now it works without any errors. However, when I click the button, the this.props.openPanel() doesn't do anything. I can see my code in the reducer getting executed, but looks like the Panel doesn't pick the new changes and doesn't appear when the redux state changes.

Comment: your reducer is wrong, it should be a pure function https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers basically you should not reassign the state, you should directly write `return {
                ...state,
                isPanelOpen: true
            }` and you can remove the `break` instruction

Comment: Oh, OK. Thanks again!